# Internet Explorer, Loading Bar, 5.57MB page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, animated-gif

I have a sorta unique question.  There is a web application which takes 5.57mbs of loading.  I want a Loading Bar or Ajax Spinner on there that animates so they know things are progressing along during the ~10-20 seconds load time.  Most is images, a lot of JS here too.   The problem here is this, Firefox correctly threads everything so the animated gif keeps spinning.  Animating.  The world is happy.  IE however loads the first few frames of the spinner, then stutter stops early and it does not do anything until the site is totally loaded.  It also locks the browser on an uncached load.  It will then show the page when loading is complete, however the spinner stops during the first frames whether it is cahced or uncached.  (A cached load is only ~2-3 seconds) Again, it does not happen in Firefox, Safari or modern browsers except for IE.  Is there a way to load IE nicely?  Research has not came up with anything yet.

Loader Code (By Request):  Note it is hard to paraphrase because of the large code base,  however this seems to capture the dilemma.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_main_gui() {
        dojo.byId("splashloader").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    function init(){
     show_main_gui();
    }
    dojo.addOnLoad(init);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#splashloader {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:999;
 width:800px;
 visibility:visible;
 height:600px;
 background:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 color:#1E4FD9;
}
</style>

<table id="splashloader"><tr><td><img src="images/interface/splashloader.gif"><span class="loader"> Loading...</span></td></tr></table>
```

A table... as it is easier to vertical align in all browsers.

IE 8 and 7 still persist with the loading gif animation freezing.  If I change the spinner to be shown after load, the animation animates.  I tried taking out all JavaScript calls other than this, and loading on cache, and it still only shows the first few frames in IE during the 1-2 second load.

Comment: Can you provide the code that generates the loader?

Comment: I would say if you can test it in IE 7 or 8 and it works (good chances it might work in 8) then forget about it. I have long ago stopped worrying about IE 6 and below users.

Comment: I added the code in the main question above.  For ref, I'm using all three IE versions, it demonstrates it in IE 7 and * as well.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but note that `style.visibility = "hidden"` will just hide the content, but keep the area it takes up as a blank section on the page. Setting `style.display = "none"` will also remove the place it takes up as if it wasn't there at all.

Comment: Actually I had used display = 'none' at first but changed it at suggestion of a forum post about animated gifs not being visible on load time perhaps causing the problem.  Using visibility vs display fixed it for this user.  It however had zero effect on my code.  I use position absolute here because even while visible it must overlay the entire cotnent.  Thank you tho :)

Comment: Yes, using position absolute will not give you the side-effect I commented...

Comment: actually, it will as an absolutely positioned item takes up no space on a page :)  So that's why I thought you were referring to it.

Comment: Still haven't got time to work on this..  I will award and answer when I do however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the content dynamically in javascript, and use your preferred technique of updating a status/progress thing. The easies is maybe to use the browser status text, but you could of course also use an area on the page to show animation and/or status.

```
<script id="postLoadJavascript" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var imagesLoaded = 0;
  var totalImages = 100;
  for(imagesLoaded = 0; imagesLoaded < totalImages; imagesLoaded++){
    window.status = 'Loading image ' + imagesLoaded + ' of ' totalImages + '...';
    document.write('<img src="image' + imagesLoaded  +'.gif" /> ');
  }
  window.status = 'Loading additional javascript...';
  document.getElementById('postLoadJavascript').src = "theAdditionalJavascript.js"
  window.status = 'Finished loading all.';

</script>
```

Comment: Another good, intriguing answer.  It might come down to doing it like this.  Thank you awe.

Comment: Turns out the dojo preloading function and doing javascript loading at the same moment (parsing a 200kB xml rules file) was causing the image to not rotate.  I used part of your solution, but went back to using the dojo one with only the javascript postloading a cached JSON version of the result of the xml rules file parse as in IE loading each image file one by one took far too long.  Firefox still tries to load all and shows the main UI before all are loaded either way, but it's alright.  Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

try put this image within an iframe. this is what gmail developers used do with that red "loading..." label in previous versions

Comment: Interesting, I had considered it but just dismissed when I saw during uncached loads it was locking other browser tabs as well.  However there is a possibility.. I'll report my result tomorrow.  Thanks Tzury.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug with animated gifs in IE. Change from an animated gif to use javascript to animate the loader thing... (e.g. by swapping images or similar)

Comment: I'll let you know if this works on uncached loads as well.  I'm guessing it isn't going to but we will see :)  One problem, several answers.  I love getting creative useful answers.  Thanks KristoferA.